# Programmers knowledge base web-based software?

Tags: web-applications, knowledge-management

I'm looking for some software (preferrably written in php or ruby) to maintain my own knowledge base. The reason why I don't think wiki-like systems are suitable for this purpose is they don't have strict categorization (manually create categories, manually assign category to article).

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You're a programmer. What's stopping you? Design a schema, come up with a UI and associated transactions, and you could have something working in a few days of mad programming. Then publish on Freshmeat and then ??? and then MONEY!

Comment: I think wordpress or whatever CMS/blog will be suitable in your case. If sphinx is not ideal for knowledge base, then build yourself one.

Answer (score 2):

I recently started using WorkFlowy.com and using it for this purpose.  Not self-hosted - but it works great for organizing your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a knowledge base software like PHPKB? Have a look at http://www.knowledgebase-script.com and try the online demo. I think it is what you are looking for.

With best regards,

Ajay Chadha

Answer (score 0):

Any good CMS (content management system) will do for you. You can't go wrong with Drupal http://drupal.org/

It's very easy to use and manage. It also has a full blown taxonomy(categories) module - just what you need.

Comment: it's too much. also drupal doesn't have such thing as "categorization" it has taxonomy, which i actually don't like. no ajax and its code style is awful (no OOP, content, php code, sql queries all mixed together). this question is the last step before writing my own app for this purpose. i've googled a lot, all solutions i've seen are very far from efficiency, speed, usability, etc... i very hope i haven't seen all possible options.

Comment: Dummy suggestion. Sorry. Drupal as a knowledge base. Really? That is like someone asking you if you want a toast, and you provide them a nice crafted iron factory.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something for a Content Management System (CMS)!

Here's a list of most of them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems

But personally I think that the best ones out there that could address your issue would be:

http://www.knowledgetree.com/ (This one specializes in knowledge bases it seems, give it a look!)
http://www.impresscms.org/
http://drupal.org/
http://www.joomla.org/

They're easy to set up and even easier to manage. Good luck!

Comment: see comment below. I've seen KnowledgeTree and tried it, everything is perfect except closed source code and propietary license :(

Comment: KnowledgeTree has a community edition that is open source, just go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/kt-dms/.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you are looking for.  I would recommend wiki style, in particular [pmwiki](http://www.pmwiki.org/).

Best of luck.

Answer (score -1):

Used by HackSpace -> http://sphinx-doc.org

See it in action here -> http://documentation.mailgun.com/#contents

Cheers!

Comment: The first link is to a documentation generator and the 2nd one is to a mail processor.  What do these have to do with a knowledge base?

Comment: `sphinx` is used to create documentation and `mailgun` is a mail processor that uses `sphinx` to generate their API documentation (AKA knowledge base) to end users. BTW I'm using `sphinx` in one of my projects as a knowledge base and it is splendid. Try to use `sphinx` you will not be disappointed.